# Mongoose Find $in Query Not Working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some code that looks like this

```
return courseModel.findQ({ autoReview: true}).then(function(autoCourses){
            autoCourses = _.pluck(autoCourses, '_id');

            console.log("autoCourses", autoCourses);

            return userCoursesModel.findQ({ 
                activityId: { 
                    $in: autoCourses
                }
            }).then(function(ucs) {
                var saves = [];

                console.log("ucs", ucs);
```

When i log "autoCourses" i see a few documents printed, and the lodash pluck should pluck out the _id's of each one. I confirmed this is working correctly.

I am using mongoose-q:

https://github.com/iolo/mongoose-q

And i tried the normal "find" as well, but no luck.

When I do a findQ({}) and find all the docs, I can see ones that match the activityId. For example:

```
autoCourses [ 55d3b57e395d0105a4828f18,
  55d4e0b8df5d4cdc23c916e2,
  55d23654642c1d05124c1ace,
  55d238b0642c1d05124c1ad2,
  55d23bb1ecce9f4b14f79c7b,
  55d257cf70721efc16db1c24,
  55d2682532eace3118376a95,
  55d2694a32eace3118376aad,
```

Also, when I log each user course activityId with a findAll, I can see that there are matches:

```
ucs.activityId 55de1dedc7c10dfc3bf5d9ae
ucs.activityId 55d3a91d46206dde7a46ed94
ucs.activityId 55df9974d8dfddb877a372f9
ucs.activityId 55d3b57e395d0105a4828f18
```

What is happening here? Why isn't the $in query working?

UPDATE:

As requested this is what the user course schema looks like:

```
var UserCourseSchema = new Schema({
    activityId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'courses',
        required: true
    },
```

and the course

```
var CourseSchema = new Schema({
    autoReview: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
```

Creating the userCourse document:

```
var newUserCourse = {
                    userId : userId,
                    activityId : activity._id,
                    steps : []
                }
                // copy steps from activity
                activity.steps.forEach(function(step){
                    newUserCourse.steps.push({partId: step._id});
                })
                return UserCourses.createQ(newUserCourse);
```

Comment: SHow us the relevant schema definitions

Comment: Seems like there must be an issue with my environment or a dependency, since no one has responded with an answer :(

Comment: It looks correct. Have you checked to see  if the data inside userCourseSchema to ensure that activityId is being populated correctly?

Comment: I have checked that, I also tested an insert and got an unusual response, the document i inserted has a strange object id: ```{
    "_id" : {
        "_bsontype" : "ObjectID",
        "id" : "Uæ_£\\\u001f³ª3¡\\P",
        "generationTime" : 1.44116e+09
    },``` while the other documents in this collection look normal (like ```"_id" : ObjectId("55cd03a556863d800c6d9955"),```

Comment: Show the insertion code, and the output.

Comment: Sorry I mean an unusual result, the response was success, and the doc was inserted properly (with the exception of the _id's), I suspect something is wrong with my version of either mongoose, mongoose-q, or mongodb driver.

Comment: No, you're likely performing the insert incorrectly. Show the code where you are performing that insert.

Comment: OK I updated the question

Comment: What about the value `activityId`? What does that look like?

Comment: The ucs console log above is showing the activity Ids, I updated the question to make this clearer, the findQ should be finding the user course with "activityId" of 55d3b57e395d0105a4828f18.

Comment: The problem is that I can't tell what is a typeof ObjectId and what is string from the console.log output as they coerce the type to string. You need to verify that the activityId is stored as `activityId: ObjectId("55d3b57e395d0105a4828f18")` and that the objects inside the array that you use in your $in operation, are of type ObjectId as well.

Comment: Set `mongoose.set("debug",true)` in your app and it should be showing the queries as sent to MongoDB. This should also be showing the `ObjectId` values as being correctly cast as such. The next thing to check is use the MongoDB shell to connect and inspect the collection data. Your schema is expecting `ObjectId` and if the query is using the correct cast "types" then the data likely does not match and is in fact a "string" or other format. If they are valid hex strings for an `ObjectId` then that should be simple to fix. But your next step will be tracking the errant code that is writing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted MongoDB support regarding this and I found that mongoose-q was using an older version of mongoose (< version 4) while my top level dependency was 4.0.5, this was causing bizarre behavior. As soon as I updated mongoose-q to 0.1.0 and mongoose to 4.1.6 and the find worked again.